# Show Magento custom (yes/no) Attribute value in success.phtml

Tags: php, magento, attributes, frontend, webshop

In a Magento webstore I am creating people can order PDF products which they will receive by email. An external system will handle these emails, this isn't part of the Magento store. On the success.phtml page I'd like to add a message for the customer if he/she has ordered a PDF product saying something like "thanks for ordering, you should get the product in your inbox soon".

I'm using the following code to get info on the order:

```
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
$itemcount=count($items);

foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
    echo 'itemcount: '.$itemcount.'<br />';
    echo 'itemname: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'itemprice: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo 'itemsku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'id: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'qty: '.$item->getQtyToInvoice().'<br />';
    echo 'pdf: '.$item->getData('pdf_ticket');
}
```

Everything gets put on the success page, except for my custom attribute `pdf_ticket`. I've also tried `getPdfTicket()`. The attribute is a Yes/No attribute. After this works I should be able to do something like `if($pdf == 'Yes'){ echo 'thanks!...' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer that worked for me by Thomas Nielsen. [Question >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568981/magento-show-custom-attribute-in-cart?rq=1)

```
$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
echo $custom->getAttributeText('pdf_ticket');
```

I'm not really sure WHY this works. So if anyone could clarify this for me, it would be great!